# How do I load dynamic location data into a dictionary object/array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary

I made a very basic dictionary that just stores a username in it, and I also want to store dynamically generated latlngs in it as well. I can already get the current latlng, and am working on how to track the location and store the new latlngs, which updates based on either distance or time.

How would I go about storing multiple latitudes under the key 'latitude' and the same for longitude?

My dictionary with the username is here:

```
username = Textbox.text;

    NSMutableDictionary *mydata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];

    [mydata setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [mydata objectForKey:@"username"]);
```

My current location code is here:

```
locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0f;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Storing them as strings will work but the encoding/decoding to a float data type is easier using NSNumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two latitudes...

```
float latitudeA;
float latitudeB;
```

that you'd like to put in an array, first "wrap" them up as NSNumbers...

```
NSNumber *numLatitudeA = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitudeA];
NSNumber *numLatitudeB = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitudeB];
```

which will let you put them in an array...

```
NSArray *myLatitudes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:numLatitudeA, numLatitudeB, nil];
```

which can be placed in your dictionary (under the key @"latitude" if you want)...

```
[myData setValue:myLatitudes forKey:@"latitude"];
```

Though, you might want to associate several latitude arrays with different unique longitudes.  If so, instead of using the string @"latitude" as the key, the longitude itself (if it's an NSNumber) can be a perfectly good key.

```
NSNumber *numLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude];
[myData setObject:myLatitudes forKey:numLongitude];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does this work with just 2 unique lat and lngs? I need the dictionary to store thousands of unique associated latlngs that will be sent from  the dictionary to a database at least once a day. Would using SQLlite be a better option for this?

Comment: That's still a pretty small quantity for the collection objects.  The thing that would drive you to the database would be (a) more like hundreds of thousands or millions, (b) complex interrelationships, (c) need to persist that data on the phone.